# [Jasig CAS+webobjects]ServiceTicket does not match supplied service error

Tags: load-testing, cas, jasig, webobjects

I'm completetly newbie to CAS configuration and i'm not the application developper, only deployer.
But as some may understand how webobjects manage CAS request I'll try asking help here :).
I'm doing load testing on WebObjects (5.3.3) web application using CAS 3.4.3.1.

I have a Webobject application with generic url:
h.tp://serv/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa

this generic url is dispatched by WebObjects on multiple instance url:
h.tp://serv/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/1
h.tp://serv/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/2
...
h.tp://serv/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/n

All these instance url are equivalents but as far I know each instance manage their own sessions.

It works fine and login service is OK with a few hundred users. But at 800 users, i'm facing this CAS error (ServiceTicket  does not match supplied, and then followed by ServiceTicket does not exist as it has been removed):

```
2013-06-27 18:25:27,888 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Added ticket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas] to registry.
2013-06-27 18:25:27,888 INFO  [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Granted service ticket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas] for service [http://server/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/1/wa/casCallBack] for user [supercoc]>
2013-06-27 18:25:57,940 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas]
2013-06-27 18:25:57,940 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Ticket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas] found in registry.
2013-06-27 18:25:57,940 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - ServiceTicket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas] with service [h.tp://server/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/1/wa/casCallBack does not match supplied service [h.tp://server/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/15/wa/casCallBack]
2013-06-27 18:25:57,940 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Removing ticket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas] from registry
2013-06-27 18:25:58,053 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas]
2013-06-27 18:25:58,053 INFO  [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - ServiceTicket [ST-49023-bwgchfenh9Z6zciIT2Pn-cas] does not exist.
```

Is there a way to force CAS to match a service instance number X:
h.tp://server/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/X
with any other service instance number Y:
h.tp://server/cgi-bin/WebObjects/CarambolPRX.woa/Y
?

Thanks for help

Comment: have you tried on the webobjects mailing list? webobjects-dev@lists.apple.com I think you need to go here to register for the mailing list: https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/webobjects-dev and checked the docs here: http://wiki.wocommunity.org/dashboard.action

Comment: Just posted on webobjects list :)